# "CREATE TABLE" statement gives error: unexpected ")" after datatype

Tags: sql-server

Given this SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.dtproperties
    ( [id]       int             NOT NULL
    , [objectid] int                 NULL
    , [property] varchar(64)     NOT NULL
    , [value]    varchar(255)        NULL
    , [uvalue]   nvarchar(510)       NULL
    , [lvalue]   image(16)           NULL
    , [version]  int             NOT NULL
    )
```

Trying to run this in an actual shell or with a SQL syntax checker online, it is expecting a closing parenthesis at `8,20`, which is located in the whitespace between `int` and `NOT NULL`. Here's an image of the checker at [sql-format.com](https://sql-format.com):

[image]

I'm not actually writing this SQL by hand - it comes from a structure dump from a Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord database connection. The legacy database it's connected to dumps fine, but syntactically does not check out. I've had to programmatically wrap all column names in square brackets because of how often reserved keywords are used as column names. So whatever this issue might be, ideally I'll be able to solve it programmatically.

Comment: To "pile on" `image` has been deprecated since 2005; that's 14 years. You should not be using it in any new projects and instead should be actively looking to change any existing projects to `varbinary(MAX)` instead.

Comment: @Larnu I appreciate your concern, I'm not strictly surprised something deprecated for so long is still in use. As I said in my original post, this is a schema dump from a legacy database, and the company I work for has virtually no control over the schema. When it becomes a real problem, the company I work for will not be responsible for fixing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`image(16)` should be `image` as the `image` datatype has never had a resolution/size.

Ideally you want to change all `image` datatypes to `varbinary(max)` as `image` won't be supported in future.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)